# Changing Angular HTTP calls to work with azure app service - MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I've deployed my app to app service, but when I try to login, I'm gettting a 502 bad gateway error. When I locally test my app. I can login with `http://localhost:3000/api/user/login` I've never deployed to cloud before, but thought it made sense to replace API call to

`https://[mywebsiteurl].azurewebsites.net/api/user/login`

, but I'm getting a 502 bad gateway error.

[image]
I'm serving my my angular files with express like this.

```
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "angular", "index.html"));
});
```

What is it I'm doing wrong. I appreciate the help!

Comment: if your server is both serving your Angular application and exposing api endpoints, why not target just `api/user/login`? You can also target the same path in development using a [development proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) via the angular cli

Comment: Makes sense. That got it working. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky You can add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the answer visible to others, I'm summarizing the answer shared in comment.

As the app service is both serving the Angular application and exposing api endpoints, we can target just `api/user/login`.

Also, we can also target the same path in development using a [development proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) via the angular cli.